# Will a Docker image built for Oracle Linux 7 run on Red Hat Linux 8

Tags: linux, docker, oracle-linux

Can a Docker image built to run on Oracle Linux 7 be run on Red Hat Linux 8 (either under Docker or cri-o/podman)?

Is there some kind of verification and/or upgrade process that can be followed? Or would I just need to build the container from scratch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one of the purposes of containers: provide a way to define the supporting infrastructure for an application (or service) and then run it anywhere that has an appropriate container runtime.

Your container should run fine on RHEL 8, regardless of where it was built. There’s nothing special to check beforehand, run the container and check that it’s working correctly.

Comment: This is for my own self-study, so I appreciate your answer.  But this confused me.  I thought Docker provided a virtualized OS, so that everything running in each container thinks it has a private copy of the OS.  I didn't think the images had the OS included with them.  I couldn't, for example, run that same Oracle Linux 7 image in a Docker container running under Windows, could I?  Or could I?

Comment: Containers share the host kernel, that’s pretty much all. So a Linux container won’t run on plain Windows. But apart from the kernel, container images contain everything that the contained application needs, including as much or as little of a distribution as necessary. Containers can contain a single binary, if it’s built appropriately, or a full-blown distribution image, if that’s what’s desired.

Comment: Thank you again.  Does Docker figure out how much is needed somehow?  Or is it up to the person building the container?  The container in question was built by Oracle Corporation.  Is it possible they purposely did not include enough of the distribution so that it would only run under Oracle Linux?

Comment: It’s up to the person building the container, or typically, the person(s) writing the `Dockerfile` (which describes the container’s contents; other approaches are possible, see [this Buildah example](https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/building-buildah)). I’m not confident enough to say it isn’t possible, but it’s unlikely a container image would run on only Oracle Linux, at least not without help from an external orchestrator (to make parts of the host system available inside the container). An image might not be *supported* on other distributions, but it should still run fine.